# Split a DataFrame in several .txt on Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to split a DataFrame based on two rows (Country and Brand) and create multiple .txt files for the combination of those two attributes. Basically, my DataFrame looks like this:

[image]

This is the code I created in case I want to split the result in to different excel files:

```
for (country, brand), group in df_f.groupby(['Country', 'Brand']):
        group.to_excel(f'{country}_{brand}.xlsx', index=False)
```

When I try to adapt this code with the following lines:

```
numpy_array = df_f.to_numpy()
np.savetxt("f'{country}_{brand}.txt", numpy_array, fmt = "%d")
```

However, it is not working. It says that this cannot be applied to a DataFrame.

How can I do this process?

Comment: 1- please provide the input as text, not image, 2- provide the expected text format, 3- why don't use use the same code as your first example with `pandas.to_csv`?

Comment: would that be working for you?
for (country, brand), group in df.groupby(['Country', 'Brand']):
        group.to_csv(f'{country}_{brand}.csv', index=False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `pandas.to_string()` and save the output into a txt file:

```py
for (country, brand), group in df_f.groupby(['Country', 'Brand']):
    s = group.to_string(index=False)
    with open(f'{country}_{brand}.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(s)
```